# Unable to Authenticate Spring Boot Thymleaf MVC Application for Load Testing Using JMeter

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-mvc, jmeter, thymeleaf

Unable to Authenticate Spring Boot Application for Load Testing Using JMeter

I'm attempting to conduct load testing on my Spring Boot application using JMeter, where I've implemented basic authentication and integrated Thymeleaf for the front end. However, I'm encountering difficulties authenticating the application during the load testing process. While I can successfully authenticate REST APIs using httpbin.org, the same method doesn't seem to work for my local Spring Boot application running on port 9094.

Here's a breakdown of the issue:

1. **Objective**: Load test URLs of the Spring Boot application following MVC pattern, which are password-protected.
2. **Method Used**: JMeter for load testing, utilizing basic authentication similar to how it's done successfully on httpbin.org.
3. **Problem**: Despite using the same methodology that works on httpbin.org for authentication, when attempting to load test my local application, the response received is the login page instead of the expected content.

**JMeter Configuration**:
I've prepared a .jmx file for the load testing process. Within this file, I've set up the HTTP Request sampler to access the URLs of the MVC pattern, and I've also configured the HTTP Authorization Manager to handle basic authentication. However, it seems that the authentication process isn't successful as it's redirecting to the login page instead of allowing access to the protected URLs.

**Sample Test Authentication**:
For instance, successful authentication on httpbin.org is achieved via the following endpoint:

- **Login URL**: https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/passwd
- **Username**: user
- **Password**: passwd

**Local Application Authentication**:
Contrarily, when attempting to replicate the same authentication method for my local Spring Boot application running on port 9094, the expected content isn't retrieved. Instead, it redirects to the login page, indicating a failure in the authentication process.

**Request for Assistance**:
I'm seeking guidance on how to correctly configure JMeter for authenticating a Spring Boot application during load testing. The aim is to access protected URLs following the MVC pattern using basic authentication within the JMeter setup.

Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this authentication issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="5.0" jmeter="5.6.2">
  <hashTree>
    <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="Test Plan" enabled="true">
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.tearDown_on_shutdown">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">false</boolProp>
      <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
      </elementProp>
    </TestPlan>
    <hashTree>
      <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Thread Group" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">1</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">1</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</stringProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.delayedStart">false</boolProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.same_user_on_next_iteration">true</boolProp>
      </ThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
        <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="HTTP Request" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.postBodyRaw">false</boolProp>
          <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" enabled="true">
            <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments">
              <elementProp name="" elementType="HTTPArgument">
                <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.always_encode">false</boolProp>
                <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
                <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.use_equals">true</boolProp>
              </elementProp>
            </collectionProp>
          </elementProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">10.14.4.49</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port">9094</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol">http</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.DO_MULTIPART_POST">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE_MULTIPART">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.image_parser">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.concurrentDwn">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.concurrentPool">6</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.md5">false</boolProp>
          <intProp name="HTTPSampler.ipSourceType">2</intProp>
        </HTTPSamplerProxy>
        <hashTree/>
        <ResultCollector guiclass="ViewResultsFullVisualizer" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="View Results Tree" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">false</boolProp>
          <objProp>
            <name>saveConfig</name>
            <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
              <time>true</time>
              <latency>true</latency>
              <timestamp>true</timestamp>
              <success>true</success>
              <label>true</label>
              <code>true</code>
              <message>true</message>
              <threadName>true</threadName>
              <dataType>true</dataType>
              <encoding>false</encoding>
              <assertions>true</assertions>
              <subresults>true</subresults>
              <responseData>false</responseData>
              <samplerData>false</samplerData>
              <xml>false</xml>
              <fieldNames>true</fieldNames>
              <responseHeaders>false</responseHeaders>
              <requestHeaders>false</requestHeaders>
              <responseDataOnError>false</responseDataOnError>
              <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>true</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
              <assertionsResultsToSave>0</assertionsResultsToSave>
              <bytes>true</bytes>
              <sentBytes>true</sentBytes>
              <url>true</url>
              <threadCounts>true</threadCounts>
              <idleTime>true</idleTime>
              <connectTime>true</connectTime>
            </value>
          </objProp>
          <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
        </ResultCollector>
        <hashTree/>
        <AuthManager guiclass="AuthPanel" testclass="AuthManager" testname="HTTP Authorization Manager" enabled="true">
          <collectionProp name="AuthManager.auth_list">
            <elementProp name="" elementType="Authorization">
              <stringProp name="Authorization.url">http://10.14.4.49:9094/</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="Authorization.username">11118</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="Authorization.password">Aa@12345</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="Authorization.domain"></stringProp>
              <stringProp name="Authorization.realm"></stringProp>
            </elementProp>
          </collectionProp>
          <boolProp name="AuthManager.controlledByThreadGroup">false</boolProp>
        </AuthManager>
        <hashTree/>
      </hashTree>
    </hashTree>
  </hashTree>
</jmeterTestPlan>
```

**Response Body**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=9CA4B513EE9EE844858D5C12EDD7E2F6; Path=/; HttpOnly
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Language: en-US
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 03 Jan 2024 10:59:07 GMT
Connection: close
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem is on JMeter end, given it's possible to authenticate successfully on httpbin with the help of [HTTP Authorization Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager).

[image]

My expectation is that given you're testing APIs you should be hitting APIs, not the server itself so maybe your URL pattern doesn't match protected areas and you're reaching the frontend instead of APIs. If JMeter would fail to authenticate you would rather get [HTTP 401](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401) status instead of 200.

In order to troubleshoot the issue from JMeter end you can [increase JMeter logging verbosity for networking components](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="org.apache.http" level="debug" />
```

and you will see all request and response details including [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header, if it's not present - your JMeter configuration is not correct,

Comment: httpbin is  an API, but I am trying to authenticate MVC application, httpbin is a rest API.